# Sourcetree caches old branches that no longer exist on github. I do not want this

Tags: version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

(Sourcetree on Mac)

This has happened for years at multiple companies.  I can't imagine it's something I'm doing wrong (or right), so perhaps it's a feature.

My coworker develops and pushes some code.  I see the branch under Remotes in Sourcetree.  She creates a PR.  I merge it and delete the branch on github.com.  I go back to Sourcetree and I still see the branch listed under Remotes.  Weeks later it is still there.  There are 2 things I can do:

- Delete the branch & push the deletion
- I, unsurprisingly, get "error: unable to delete 'branchA': remote ref does not exist"

or

- I can check out the branch!
- I check it out with no problem, and when I commit and push to origin it "remembers" the history of branch as if it was always there, it's not as if I created a new branch with the same name

Is this supposed to happen?  There is an option "Keep backups on destructive operations" in the Sourcetree Settings.  Maybe it's a feature?